# Are Bell's inequality and CHSH inequality the same?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology, definition, bells-inequality, epr-experiment

Are [Bell's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem) and [CHSH inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHSH_inequality) different? I tried to read about them and I understood that both disprove local hidden variable theory but I do not understand how they are different(if they are so...), except for their respective mathematics used in the derivation.

Comment: see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AE8MaQJkRcg and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1twSZF4fLM for explanation of Bell test, CHSH and Bell are generally similar.

Comment: No, they are different inequalities with different hypoteses.

Comment: They are different inequalities but they have the same spirit, i.e., they are both conditions that a local realistic theory must obey but which QM may violate